# dbms_sql.define_column_long procedure is throwing ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got LONG BINARY

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a column in my table which is defined as `LONG RAW` type, and this column has some records which are more than 32kb in size.
I searched the Internet on how can I fetch a LONG RAW value which is more than 32k, so I got some answer for fetching it in multiple chunks.

But when I tried to implement that solution I got some error which I am not able to resolve.

I do not have the privilege in DB to create a function or create a new table, so I tried to implement solution as below,

```
set serveroutput on size 100000 
declare
p_long_col char(123):='MESSAGE';
p_source varchar2(200):='USR_MESSAGE_ARCHIVE';
v_sql   VARCHAR2(32767) := 'select %l% from %v% where rownum<2 ';
v_piece VARCHAR2(32767);
v_clob  CLOB;
v_plen  INTEGER := 32767;
v_tlen  INTEGER := 0;
v_rows  NUMBER(38);
v_csr   number;
begin 
 v_sql := REPLACE(REPLACE(v_sql, '%l%', p_long_col), '%v%', p_source);
v_csr := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
dbms_sql.parse( v_csr, v_sql, dbms_sql.native );
dbms_sql.define_column_long(v_csr, 1);
if (dbms_sql.EXECUTE_AND_FETCH(v_csr)>0) then
loop
DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE_LONG(v_csr, 1, 32767, v_tlen, v_piece, v_plen);
           v_clob := v_clob || v_piece;
           v_tlen := v_tlen + 32767;
           EXIT WHEN v_plen < 32767;
END LOOP;
end if;
DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(v_csr);
end;
```

Below is the error I am seeing:-

```
Error report -
    ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got LONG BINARY
    ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1837
    ORA-06512: at line 18
    00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
```

The line number in error tells that it is throwing error at:- 
    dbms_sql.define_column_long(v_csr, 1);

I am new to PL/SQL, so kindly suggest me on this issue, it will be really helpful.

Comment: If you do not have the privilege  speak to your supervisor or people who can assist you in providing that. Write and test the code you wish in a Dev environment and ask a super user / DBA to execute it on your behalf. Relying on and piling up workarounds like this in your application simply to bypass permissions is not a wise way to get going on something.

Comment: Moreover, it is important to understand that LONG columns are supported only for backward compatibility. Oracle also recommends that you convert existing LONG columns to LOB columns.So, it is worthwhile to take a step in that direction rather than using workarounds.

Comment: LONG is not the same as LONG RAW. Over 32k you need to use C or Java or similar to process a long raw. Its one of the reasons its so much nicer to see if you can move to LOB (CLOB, BLOB etc)